# How to configure and looking up OSGi service via JNDI

Tags: java, osgi, jndi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle

I have created a OSGi bundle using bundle activator and deployed in karaf,
but in karaf if you give jndi:bind-id service-name  then it will not exist after karaf console shutdown because its not persistent.

I want to register service in OSGi using JNDi which is persistent, which is I can access using JNDI.

I am registering service as under,

```
 bundleContext.registerService(myFramework.class.getName(),FrmFactory.initFramework(ctx), null);
Context ctx = null;
        try
        {
            ctx = new InitialContext();
            ctx.bind("service/myframework", frmFactory.initFramework(ctx));
        }
```

Please suggest is this the right way,if not Please suggest,
because I am getting exception as

> errorMessage = jndiobjectBindError, errorMessage = Failed to bind
>   local object in jndi. Object Name:service/portframework, cause =
>   javax.naming.NotContextException: The intermediate context Myfr
>   amework does not exist

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to access services using jndi in karaf is to use the ["jndi" feature](http://aries.apache.org/modules/jndiproject.html). It provides access to all OSGi services using jndi.

For your case the jndi name of your service would be:

```
osgi:service/<FQN of myFramework>
```

So you just have to register your service and do not need to care about also registering in jndi.

Comment: thanks Christian for your quick response but my doubt is ,let say I have a bundle name MyFramework which I deployed in karaf I want to provide permanently JNDI name which should not go after console close, so that other client can use that service using JNDI access, I have given command as  under getting error message                                                         karaf@root()> osgi:service/myframeworkservice
Command not found: osgi:service/portframeworkservice

Comment: What I wrote is a jndi name not a command. It is independent of the karaf console. Why do you need jndi at all? How do you use it?

Comment: I need JNDI because I have deployed a bundle(e.g. bundle1 MyFramework) as service using bundleActivator (OSGi) ,my other bundle will be using bundle1 using JNDI thats why I need to assign JNDI for bundle1

Comment: Just use the jndi url I gave above in the bundle that wants to access MyFramework. You do not need to use additional shell commands. You should consider though to access MyFramework through the service instead. It works much better with the OSGi dynamics. JNDI has no means to communicate the a service is removed. So if you have this dynamic in your deployment jndi is not so good.

Comment: please can you share some examples because I am new in all this

Comment: You can take a look at my karaf tutorials. They all show how to work with services. http://liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/Karaf+Tutorials